# LLVM: simple way to cast types?

Tags: c++, casting, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm looking for a **simple** way to cast types using the LLVM C++ api.
What I'm trying to avoid is endless nested if-else checks what will pick the right IR cast instruction.
Here's an example code that I'd like to get working:

```
int x = 0;
int64_t y = (int64_t) x;
```

Is there a way to cast types without checking what type it is? Obviously a type conversion from a struct to a float is stupid and should fail but how can I **simply** pick the right instruction?

Also I'm using this as a reference: https://mapping-high-level-constructs-to-llvm-ir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic-constructs/casts.html
because the official LLVM docs aren't very helpful.

Comment: What nested if-else checks are you talking about?

Comment: The different instructions do different things, as in, produce different bits in the output. There are utility functions like "CastInst::CreateIntegerCast" and "CastInst::CreateTruncOrBitCast" which might be the sort of thing you want? See https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html .

Comment: @NickLewycky huge thanks! I didn't even know these functions existed

Comment: OK! I'll copy it to answer then!

Answer (score 1):

The different instructions do different things, as in, produce different bits in the output. There are utility functions like "CastInst::CreateIntegerCast" and "CastInst::CreateTruncOrBitCast" which might be the sort of thing you want? See llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html .